# How do I split a single WPML site with 6 languages (English is Main) into Multisite with 5 subfolders

Tags: multisite, directory, export, plugin-wpml

I'm working on a huge WPML website with 6 different languages (english is main .com) and I'd like to convert it into a multisite with subdirectory structure instead of the .com/?language= structure.

I haven't worked with WMPL before, and the documentation is a little lacking.  There is no feature to export the content of just one language, and the website bonks when trying to export the entire content xml file.

I've tried exporting the database directly, but writing a query to export the language tables is a nightmare.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: if the content is all going to be the same, what do you need multisite for? if you want to change the URL structure you can do a .htaccess rewrite so that, for example, all URLs with /es/ are automatically rewritten to /?language=es (/es/ will continue to show in the browser )

Comment: @majick We've decided to go with multisite to make it easier for our staff in other countries to add or change content for their language without having to go through the admin of the main site.